# How do I print the HTML element hidden in Zend_Form_Element_Select?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form which I create manually (a lot of JavaScript in it...). I am using the Zend_Form classes on the server side to validate input and some more.

Is there a way to get a Zend_Form_Element_Select (or any other element) to be rendered without rendering the entire Zend_Form object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like,

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select(...);
echo $element->render();
```

?

That will render only a Select element, not an entire form.

That method is defined in the Zend_Form_Element class that is the parent of all the Zend_Form_Element_* classes. See the [API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Element/Zend_Form_Element.html#render) for more information.

Comment: That's right, I forgot that Zend returns strings instead of making echoes.